# Putting together many large txt files...my first line is misaligned for some reason

Tags: arrays, regex, perl, reference

Final Edit: Thanks to some input here I fixed my problem! Project complete! The code below works. Its quite speedy with ~100 txt files (about 2000 lines and 10 columns each), but any suggestions to make this faster would be cool!

I have several folders with a year's worth of data. Within these folders are many txt files.

In the top row is the header name. The second row are the units. Two headers can be the same, but are different because the units are different.In some years we collected a certain kind of data (such as turbidity) but in other years we didnt.

Sample Data:

EX1

```
DateTime    Temp    SpCond  Salinity    DO% DO Conc DO Charge   Depth   pH  pHmV    Chlorophyll %Fluorescence
M/D/Y   C   mS/cm   ppt %   mg/L        m       mV  ug/L    %FS
2/17/2009 14:01 2.79    45.303  28.45   124.4   13.87   46  1.092   8.56    -93.4   4.7 1.1
```

EX2

```
Date/Time   Temp    Speci Cond  Salinity    DO  DO  DO Charge   Depth   pH  pH
mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss °C  mS/cm   PPT %   mg/L    DOchrg  meters  pH  mV
7/13/2010 13:31 23.52   46.821  30.44   72.8    5.19    39  9.369   7.69    -46.3
```

OUTPUT:

```
Date/Timemm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss    TemperatureÂ°C  Specific CondmS/cm  SalinityPPT DO% DOmg/L  DO ChargeDOchrg Depthmeters pHpH    pHmV    Chlorophyllug/L ChlorophyllRFU  Temperature°C   ConductivitymS/cm   ResistivityKOhm.cm  TDSg/L  Densityg/cm3    

1/15/2010 13:30 2.41    49.78   31.49   129.7   14.31   98  1.108   8.08    -85.6   7.7 1.8 -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999
1/15/2010 13:45 2.26    49.708  31.42   126.7   14.03   98  1.104   8.08    -85.7   9.1 2.2 -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999
1/15/2010 14:00 2.23    49.664  31.38   126.3   14  99  1.092   8.1 -86.5   8.5 2   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999
1/15/2010 14:15 2.19    49.685  31.39   125.1   13.88   97  1.091   8.11    -87 8.3 2   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999
1/15/2010 14:30 2.22    49.703  31.41   125.3   13.89   99  1.105   8.11    -87.5   8.4 2   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999
```

Code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl



#procedure
#1-find all unique headers in each file
#2-put the data from each file into a new one that is defined by the unique headers

use Tie::File;  #each txt file is represented as an array

my @tog=(); #where I will store the headers and units I find
my @lines=();
{
     opendir my $CWD, '.' or die "opendir .: $!\n";

    my @files = grep /\.txt$/i, readdir $CWD; #read the txt file
    closedir $CWD;
    for (@files) {
        tie my @lines, 'Tie::File', $_ or die $!;
            my @headers = split(/\t/,$lines[0]); 
            my @units=split(/\t/,$lines[1]);        
            for( my $i=0 ; $i<=$#headers; $i++){
            my $one= join "",$headers[$i],$units[$i];
            chomp($one);
            push(@tog,$one);
            }
            }


}

#1-get the unique headers
my %seen;
@tog = grep { ! $seen{$_}++ } @tog; #get the unique headers of all the files in the folder
@tog = grep {$_} @tog;

my $UH=@tog;
my @headers=();
#create a new file's headers name based on unique header name
for( my $f=0; $f<=$UH; $f++){
    print "$tog[$f] \t $f\n"; #when I do this I see that I haven't gotten rid of the blank ones!
    push(@headers, $tog[$f]); # create header based on unique variable
}


open my $fh, '>', 'DATAEXPORT.txt' or die "Could not open file: $!"; #declare your function handle fh. this will do the writing
print $fh join("\t", @headers), "\n";

#2-put the data from each file into a new one that is defined by the unique headers
{    
    opendir my $CWD, '.' or die "opendir .: $!\n";
    my @files = grep /\.txt$/i, readdir $CWD; #read the txt file
    closedir $CWD;      
    for (@files) {
    my @search=();  
        tie my @lines, 'Tie::File', $_ or die $!;
            my @headers = split(/\t/,$lines[0]); 
            my @units=split(/\t/,$lines[1]);    
            for( my $i=0 ; $i<=$#units; $i++){
            my $one= join "",$headers[$i],$units[$i];
            chomp($one);
            push(@search,$one);
            }       
        my @expr=@tog;
        @pattern= grep {$_} @search;
#this is the array that contains the headers and units of the particular file I am looking at       
            #Now that I have read what matches the expression, I should use these things to write into a txt file

    my $Nlines=$#lines; #grab the number of lines you will be working with  
        for( my $j=0; $j<=$Nlines; $j++){
            $rownum=$j;     
                my @dataline_array=split(/\t/,$lines[$j]);
                my @datarow=();
                for(my $i=0; $i<=$#expr; $i++){                             
                    $found=0;
                    for(my $ii=0; $ii<=$#pattern; $ii++){ #Do this until you are cycling through all data points                                                                                    
                        if ($pattern[$ii] =~ m/$expr[$i]/){                         
                            $found=1;
                            chomp($dataline_array[$ii]);
                            push(@datarow,$dataline_array[$ii]);
                        }
                    }                   
                    if($found eq 0){ #if we looked through all of them, and didn't find a match
                    push(@datarow,'-9999');
                    }
                    undef $found;                   
                    #loop through each expression                
                }
                #do this for every row you write                
                open(my $fh, '>>', 'DATAEXPORT.txt') or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!"; #open an append to bottom of file
                print $fh join("\t",@datarow), "\n";
                close $fh;

                undef @datarow;

        }
        #Now that we have gone through all of our lines, lets print out doc 
        undef @expr;
        undef @pattern;     
        }
}
```

Comment: How is this different from the first edit of [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20356578/how-can-i-get-the-index-of-matching-array-contents)? It is very hard to understand what you're trying to achieve, or even what your question is. Perhaps you could think about how to make your goal clearer and edit your first question instead of asking yet another unclear question.

Comment: Your code appears to be missing a closing brace near the end; it's not clear where it should go, however.

Comment: Does your approach work? Then I think it's great. It doesn't work? then ask a real question: tell us what the problem is.

Comment: It is matching the values correctly (unique header, current header) I am going as I go. Right now I am checking to see if the array was actually populated. I have never worked with them before, so if someone can correct me when I make the array.

Comment: Okay so I made progress and now I am stuck. I am not sure why the first row of my out put is off and I can't see to get rid of blanks. halp!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting blank fields when you split the headers of the file, then instead of

```
my @headers = grep { /\S/ } split(/\t/,$lines[0]);
my @units=grep { /\S/ } split(/\t/,$lines[1]);
```

try this:

```
my @headers = split /\s*\t\s*/, $lines[0];
my @units = split /\s*\t\s*/, $lines[0];
```

My guess is that some of the field separators have spaces mixed in with the tabs, and that is making it difficult to parse them cleanly into `@headers` and `@units`. The regular expression `\s*\t\s*` means "a string of whitespace that includes at least one tab", so it should automatically remove any extraneous whitespace for you.

Some general suggestions and thoughts:

- Using `Tie::File` means that if you modify one of the elements of `@lines`, that change will update the contents of the file. I don't *think* this is what you want to do. If not, it may be a lot safer to do this instead:

  ```
  open(FILE, $_) or die $!;
  @lines = <FILE>;
  close FILE;
  ```
- It doesn't look like there's any difference between the `@headers` array and `@tog`. You could just drop the code that copies `@tog` into `@headers`.
- The code that combines `@headers` and `@units` in each file could be moved into a subroutine to make it a little easier to understand your code:

  ```
  sub combined_headers_and_units {
      my ($header_line, $units_line) = @_;
      chomp $header_line;
      chomp $units_line;
      my @headers = split /\s*\t\s*/, $header_line;
      my @units = split /\s*\t\s*/, $units_line;
      my @combined = ();
      for( my $i=0 ; $i <= $#headers; $i++) {
          my $one= join ",",$headers[$i],$units[$i];
          push @combined, $one;
      }
      return @combined;
  }
  ```

  Then:

  ```
  for (@files) {
      open (FILE, $_) or die $!;
      my $header_line = <FILE>;
      my $units_line = <FILE>;
      close FILE;
      push @tog, combined_headers_and_units($header_line, $units_line);
  }
  ```

I would be happy to make other suggestions, but it's very hard to understand what you're trying to do with the data you have. If you can describe more specifically what your goal is and what you want the output to look like, we can try to give you more specific suggestions for fixing the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! Actually I have just fixed this problem, and you were correct, some data had space. I fixed my problem with 1) @tog = grep {$_} @tog; and 2) chomp($dataline_array[$ii]). Now everything is alighed perfectly...except the first line is still wrong. I don't know why!

Comment: I wish I could suggest something else, but I still don't understand what you are trying to do, other than combine data from different files in some sort of interesting way.

Comment: JK I tested this on a folder with 200 txt files and it worked just fine. Project complete!

Comment: NP, I am not very good at asking questions. Anyways I am glad this project is done! Maybe someone else will have a problem like this (especially large environmental science data sets) and it could be useful!

Comment: Ah I just saw your edits, they are very helpful and I wanted to make that combination section into a sub, I just didn't know how to make it  work. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to be able to help :-)